# How to generate dynamic li's id in wp_list_categories

Tags: wordpress

```
<ul class="tabs">
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=date&show_count=1&title_li=');?>
</ul>
```

its shows

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-1">
    <a title="View all posts filed under Uncategorized" href="--">Uncategorized</a>
  </li>
```

but i want to put 
      `<li id="tab(1 to more)" class="cat-item cat-item-1">`------
    like this. how to do???

Answer (score 0):

add_filter function will help you.

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories','add_id_to_li');

function add_id_to_li($output){
   return  // do something  
}
```

Comment: hey gowri ... what may be in return function ...i did put li static in wp-include-> category-tamplate.php line 449... but i can't see the id... :( how can i'll do with ur code. i'm just new to wordpress functions...

Comment: Don't hack core code. add this code in your template function.php.you need to play with regular expression to insert id.

Comment: @user1813928: i am not good with regular expression. I try to get this.